# Detecting NON mobile browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'd like to redirect mobile users to a different page. But instead of trying to detect any number of mobile browsers, I'd just like to see if the user is using IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, or Opera; all other users go to the mobile site.

My biggest problem is detecting regular Safari from mobile Safari.

Any good way to do this?

Comment: Don't mind that Konqueror users would hit the mobile site? Just trying to illustrate that maintaining UA sniffing code for desktop UAs is not necessarily going to be any easier than the reverse :)

Comment: Not really, I only need to support those 5 main browsers.

Comment: those kinds of remarks are reckless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd ask me, if you stay away from Flash/Silverlight applets, and you don't overdo CSS 3 selectors (although as time passes by, this will become less of a problem...), you really don't need to use browser-specific directions.

Using a reset CSS style-sheet would help also. Go see that link for that matters :

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/